How to set up file structure for zephyr testing
I am using the Zephyr test framework on Windows.
I am trying to incorporate library unit testing in zephyr however what I am struggling with is being able to set up the project such that the files are able to link with each other while testing.
To my understanding:

CMake files are going to help link all of your files based on the directories that are included.
testframe.yaml is the file that is used by twister to determine what tests are going to be run and how.

When running the west build -t run -b qemu_cortex_m3 -p in the test folder to simulate the unit tests on hardware.
I get the following error:
C:/Users/bhupi/Git_Projects/nrf9160-feather-examples-and-drivers/tests/adc_control/src/test_adc_control.c:2:10: fatal error: adc_control.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "adc_control.h"

I understand that the system is not able to locate where the adc_control.h file is, however I am doing this by telling the main CMake file to include the sub directory through: zephyr_include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/lib)  which should read the include/lib folders for header files to include. The header file is not showing a linking error to the source file (.c) so I am assuming that the linking between them is not an issue.
The below is the project files, is anyone able to help me understand what I m doing incorrectly in regards to this error?
I have uploaded the project files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Pswd7AoJupxNndUVEKtGolYaR_eg_6Ws?usp=drive_link
Let me know if more information is needed to help in understanding the problem.
Thanks everyone.

Based on the directory structure of the linked project, the header file is not in include/lib but is in include/lib/adc_control. Include paths are not recursively searched, but you can include the directory in the code:
#include "adc_control/adc_control.h"

